2024 bitbake "install" .bb command function fails to copy license file, indicates syntax error when I use bitbake -p
# Add the license file after unpacking the source
do_unpack:append() {
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/MNI.LIC ${S}/MNI.LIC || die "Failed to copy license file"
}

bitbake -p results in:
....
', 'FILESPATH', 'PRSERV_DUMPDIR', 'PARALLEL_MAKE', 'STAGING_DIR_TARGET', 'BB_WORKERCONTEXT', 'SSTATE_DIR', 'LICENSE_PATH', 'PRSERV_LOCKDOWN', 'PRSERV_DUMPFILE', 'PWD'}, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7fcbfaefa050>):
                     parser = bb.codeparser.PythonParser(key, logger)
    >                parser.parse_python(value, filename=varflags.get("filename"), lineno=varflags.get("lineno"))
                     deps = deps | parser.references
  File "/home/mnidev/work/tisdk/sources/bitbake/lib/bb/codeparser.py", line 319, in PythonParser.parse_python(node='\n    bb.build.exec_func(\'base_do_unpack\', d)\n    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/MNI.LIC ${S}/MNI.LIC || die "Failed to copy license file"\n', lineno=1, filename='autogenerated'):
             node = "\n" * int(lineno) + node
    >        code = compile(check_indent(str(node)), filename, "exec",
                            ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "autogenerated", line 3
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/MNI.LIC ${S}/MNI.LIC || die "Failed to copy license file"
               ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

ERROR: Parsing halted due to errors, see error messages above
I've also used 0644. Flumoxed.

Good results would be to copy the file to the working folder.
Obvious next step (which I should not have to do) but saw as recomended is to check this in to the remote repo and have it pull down the file. That's easy, and what I'll do now.
Just wondering if others have seen this issue.
Also, it would be great if the yocto had a simple cplusplus reference for all the *.bb and *.bbappend recipe commands. searching for install on their main page just gets you into the whole how to install the apparatus.
**UPDATE: **
The license file was required for yocto build purposes only.
Thus the install only needed:
'''
do_install() {                                                                                                             echo "S is set to: ${S}"                                                                                               echo "B is set to: ${D}"                                                                                               install -d ${D}/root/MyApp                                                                                               install -m 0755 ${S}/bin/MyApp ${D}/root/APP
}
'''
And this worked correctly.

Perhaps you should take another approach - add the LICENSE file as patch and append it with SRC_URI, then it will be added automatically done by the bitbake.

Thanks, I now realize several ways to move the file over.  do_patch, do_install, need to test these, but the syntax error was what is troubling.  TBD - WIP
do_install() {
install -d ${D}${datadir}/licenses/${PN}
install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/MNI.LIC ${D}${datadir}/licenses/${PN}/MNI.LIC
}

Yocto error/warning messages can be really confusing, even more than C++ ;-). do_patch will overwrite the existing file, I thought the file already exist there. With do_install you can append any additional file, if it exist on source directory. To see it on rootfs you have to use FILES:${PN}:append too. Its easier with eLBaaS! :)
